# String can't get inside the broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new in android, trying to develop an application.I have a BroadcastReceiver class and an activity class.it is created for managing the audio control(silent,ring,vibrate).That is while receiving an SMS receiver checks the message body and comparing it with user given keyword(using edit Text in activity page) Here I faced a trouble that, I passed this string (editText value to broadcastReceiver).It reached there but inside the try block this string variable being null.Any one can help me...

**Activity class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {.....

.......

acivatebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){....
....public void onClick(View v) {

String kslnt=txtkeysilent.getText().toString();....

Intent intent = new Intent("package.action.string");
            if (checksilnt.isChecked()){intent.putExtra("extra", kslnt);}
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver Class**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

AudioControl audio;

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

private AudioManager myAudioManager;

public String silent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

    if(action.equals("package.action.string")){
        silent = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

       /* int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+  state+rng+vbrt, duration);
        toast.show();*/
    }

    myAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE );

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);


                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().toString();

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+  state+rng+vbrt, duration);
                toast.show();
                Log.i("SmsReceiver","message:" + message);
                if (message.equals(silent )){myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}


                this.abortBroadcast();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
    }
}
```

}

here the value 'silent' should contain the keyword (from the activity editText)

`if (message.equals(silent )){myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}`

but silent shows a null value...

in this block it shown correctly (editText string is shown here)

```
 String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
    if(action.equals("package.action.string")){
        silent= intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

       /* int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+  state+rng+vbrt, duration);
        toast.show();*/
    }
```

Comment: have you debugged the `onReceive` method? does the if works and `silent` is assigned with value?? as it might not have a value because you are passing it's value depending on a condition!

Comment: Yes I debugged this program,there is no error. ' if.' is working but it not what i expect . value of silent is assigned from the activity class.' s editText

Comment: Debug and check the value of checksilnt.isChecked() this in activity . is it false or true...

Comment: have you registered your `BroadCastReciver'?

Comment: yes. registered BroadCastReciver

Comment: @suhailmc I see that you send the value to the receiver twice, one at `onCreate` and other at some button click, which case is the problem? and what value do u expect? do you expect the value of text from the edittext?

Comment: Sorry in onCreate,, it is for checking. It is only at button click.

Comment: I expect the value of text from edittext

Comment: i don't see any thing wrong, just double check the condition from the btn event, debug and make sure of the condition is true and the value is added to the intent before sending it to the receiver!

Comment: value is received on the the receiver but it can't in try block

Comment: please add the error log

Comment: 02-11 11:26:19.344 29996-29996/com.example.raheem.puresecure E/SmsReceiver: Exception smsReceiverjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
02-11 11:26:30.884 29996-30503/com.example.raheem.puresecure E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0

Comment: this error is very far of the string `silent`, i think it is in the array `pdusObj` , the bundle seems not have any thing called "pdus"!!

Comment: and please when adding error logs, u should edit the post and add the log as like code

Comment: @suhailmc please check the answer it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

> but silent shows a null value...

Issue is while broadcasting data/intent you've put string value in `Intent` & at the time of retriving you are trying to get that string from `Intent`'s extras which would be `Bundle`. So to resolve this you need to get it from `Intent` not from `Intent` extras (`Bundle`).

You have put values like

```
intent.putExtra("extra", kslnt);
```

It **should not** be like (Specifically in your case as you are not putting values in `Bundle`)

```
silent = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
```

So you **should get values** like below

```
intent.getStringExtra("extra");
```

*Specifically your method with correction*

```
String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
    if(action.equals("package.action.string")){
        //silent= intent.getExtras().getString("extra"); // this is wrong
        intent.getStringExtra("extra"); //get String from intent getStringExtra method (Because you have put string values in Intent not in Intent's putExtras's (Bundle)
       /* int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+  state+rng+vbrt, duration);
        toast.show();*/
    }
```

Let me know if anything

Comment: have u looked at his error log! he added it to comments

Comment: @AtefHares I checked question and it is mentioned  **but silent shows a null value...** and i guess my answer will solve **null value** related issue.

Comment: `String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
    if(action.equals("package.action.string")){
        silent= intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
       
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG; 
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+  state+rng+vbrt, duration);
        toast.show();
    }`

Comment: this is the part of `onReceive` method..while toasting here silent have a string value(text of edit text).

Comment: but inside the `try`block it it become null value ` if (message.equals(silent )){myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}
`

Comment: It is OK sir. but problem is not here.`if (message.equals(silent )){myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}`  here while Toasting the value of `silent` is null...here is the problem. it is in the `try` bloack

Comment: `02-11 12:40:32.204 23007-23007/com.example.raheem.puresecure E/EmojiFactory_jni: Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found` it is one of the line in the log,is it an error ?

Answer (score 0):

This trouble is arises due to non initialization of AudioManager, here it is only declared, not initialized

```
myAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

I solve this problem by adding this line